# Why can't I make an abstract method static in my implementation?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

Let's assume the following scenario in Java

```
public interface Foo {
    Object bar();
}

public class Baz implements Foo {
    public Object bar() {
        //My implementation
    }
}
```

Why can I not make `Baz.bar()` static?

Doing so results in the compiler error `This static method cannot hide the instance method from Foo` Adding an `@Override` annotation to `Baz.bar()` changes the compiler error to `The method bar() of type Baz must override or implement a supertype method`

It seems to me that from the perspective of anyone using the interface `Foo`, the implementing class `Baz` would still fulfill the interface requirements, while making a method that has a static implementation available to anyone who is explicitly using the `Baz` class without instantiation.

How come the compiler doesn't allow this scenario?

**Edit**:

Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but what I'm actually asking is ***why*** this isn't allowed, since from my point of view, I'm not decreasing the visibility of the interface-defined method.

And yes, I know I used the word abstract in the title, and not in the question, but that's because the `abstract` keyword is implied in an interface.

**Edit 2**:

I'll add an example that is closer to reality for clarity on why I am even asking this:

```
public interface DatabaseMapper<T extends DatabaseType> {
    Entry<T> convert(Entry);
}

public interface SQL extends DatabaseType {}

public class SQLEntry implements Entry<SQL> {}

public class SQLMapper implements DatabaseMapper<SQL> {
    public SQLEntry convert(Entry e) {
        //Convert some generic entry to the SQLEntry type
    }
}
```

In this case, I want to force all `Mapper` implementations to implement the `convert` method, but at the same time, this method might not depend in any way on the internal state of an `SQLMapper` object, and it might be desirable to be able to convert a generic `Entry` into a `SQLEntry` without going through an instantiation-process that probably includes database connection strings and the like.

This was the scenario I was faced with, and why I wanted to see if anyone knew why this was not possible to accomplish with the same method - e.g. not having to resort to a `public static SQLEntry convertStatic(Entry e)` which the overridden method delegates its implementation to.

Again though, I understand that this is not possible in Java due to how the compiler works - I am simply trying to understand *why that is*.

Comment: Can you also show how your client is going to call this code? not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Updated to include a real world use case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real answer is that Java simply wasn't defined this way. In other language, this is possible.

For instance, in Scala there aren't static methods, but you can instead define static `object` that are singleton and that allow this. In dynamic language like Smalltalk or Ruby, classes are like objects, and this is also possible.

But in Java, static methods are similar to global methods. There is not concept of `self`, nor `super` in a static method because it's not bound to an object. By consequence inheritance/overriding doesn't really apply.

It unfolds that if there is no notion of inheritance, it also doesn't make sense to speak of `abstract`.

Comment: I'm begrudgingly accepting that the best answer is "because Java wasn't defined this way."  Thanks for expanding on inheritance of class objects

Answer (score 1):

Abstract methods are supposed to be overridden (Defined) by a subclass method. You can't override static methods as they do not pertain to an instance but to the specific class they are defined.

For example a non static method is used as such:

```
Foo b = new Baz();
Object result = b.bar();
```

static is used as such:

```
Object result = Baz.bar2();
```

if you really want bar to be static and also an override at the instance level do this:

```
public interface Foo {
    Object bar();
}

public class Baz implements Foo {
    @Override
    public Object bar() {
          return Baz.bar2();
    }
    public static Object bar2() {
     //your implementation
    }

}
```

Comment: your answer makes me want to downvote the OP for either including the word `abstract` in his title, or excluding the word `abstract` from his question

Comment: @JDPeckham - your suggested solution doesn't compile due to duplicate methods `bar()` in `Baz`...

Comment: @Joel Westberg sorry didn't have a java compiler. You could call the static method whatever you want because it won't break clients of the interface. I'll change it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Baz implements Foo {
    public Object bar() {
        //My implementation
    }
 public static  Object bar() {
        //My implementation
    }
}
```

because, your method signatures are same, bar () is not overloaded. as you have declared a non-static bar() in your abstract class, you are forced to implement that method in this class.

Comment: `final` is allowed though, so why isn't `static`? I honestly can't see how I'm decreasing the visibility of the method in any way with the `static` keyword.

Comment: static changes it from instance level to global level. You can't polymorph a global method so therefore you can't make a polymorphic method global. Final says it's read only/immutable. try reading this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords

Comment: @JDPeckham.. You should not say its `global` level. It changes the whole meaning of `static keyword`. Rather it's from `instance level` to `class level`.

Comment: @JoelWestberg it hides the `public Object bar(), because it has the same name as the interface method without actually over-writing it

Comment: @SamIam I understand that, I'm asking the question: why can't it override the interface method? I'm asking from a language design perspective, not because I don't understand the compiler error.

Comment: @JoelWestberg  because there can only be 1 static `bar`  you can have a instance `bar` for every instance of BAZ

Comment: @Rohit Jain Good point! ie private static wouldn't be global :)